# Using for loop to iterate two variables together

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, increment

How do I go about doing something like this?

Say I have an array `x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])` of `length 5`,

```
for i,j in range(len(x)):
```

I want `i` and `j` to increment together.

This is throwing me an error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-37d0ddc3decf> in <module>()
----> 1 for i,j in range(len(x)):
      2     print i,j
      3 

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

The reason I need this is because I have to use it in a condition inside the for loop. Like say, `y[i][j]` and I want this to be `0,0` then `1,1` and so on.

Comment: you probably mean to use `enumerate` but i don't understand your desired output

Comment: @JulienSpronck I would like both `i` and `j` to increment together

Comment: sure but you want both of them to be equal to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?

Comment: as I have to use it in a condition inside the for loop. Like say, `y[i][j]` and I want this to be 0,0 then 1,1 and so on

Comment: `range(len(x))` is a 1D array and you can not use 2 variable for unpacking. at all! can you show us whats your desire output?

Comment: then just do `for i in range(len(x)): ... y[i][i]`. you don't need two variables

Comment: @JulienSpronck Yeah that makes sense to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edited answer***

OP says

> The reason I need this is because I have to use it in a condition inside the for loop. Like say, y[i][j] and I want this to be 0,0 then 1,1 and so on.

In that case, you could simply use:

```
y[i][i]
```

---

***Original answer***

I'm not really sure why you would want to do that, you could just set it in the first line of the for loop:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    j = i
    ... #rest of the code follows
```

You could also use `enumerate`, as pointed in comments by @Julien, like below (but IMO, the earlier method is better):

```
>>> for i, j in enumerate(xrange(len(x))):
...     print i, j
... 
0 0
1 1
2 2
```

Comment: "In that case, you could simply use ...` ... it's true in all cases, if `j` is always equal to `i`, just use `i`

Comment: @JulienSpronck Before OP clarified that, it was possible he might have needed to change `j` in the duration of his for loop; but once he clarified, that possibility turned remote, and hence the wording of the current answer.

Comment: I think you should remove the `enumerate` solution. It's just nonsense to do such a thing.

Comment: @Maxime The whole question is nonsense IMO. I left it there because it was a possible way to do what OP was asking in his question initially.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need `j` in the first place? If `j` is always equal to `i`, just use `i`. No need for a second variable.

Comment: I totally agree.. I realise my mistake now!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
for i, j in zip(range(len(x)), range(len(x))):
    print i, j
```

So the question is about how to iterate two variables, not why ;-)